# How to use Cypari package in python?

Tags: python, pari

I searched instruction documents or manuals on [cypari](https://pypi.org/project/cypari/) but couldn't found, I found  the below code only -

```
import cypari
print(cypari.pari('factor({})'.format(2**127-2)))
```

So, I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your command, the result is like a pair of lists. The first one contains the primes, the second the multiplicities.
To convert it into dictionary format like `sympy.ntheory.factorint`, you can use

```
res = cypari.pari('factor({})'.format(2**127-2))
d = {res[0][i] : res[1][i] for i in range(len(res[0]))}
```